# Trouble with Flexbox-fitting all the elements within container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm following this tutorial but the css he provides renders a little differently for me, I'm not sure why. The last section with the four icons aren't displaying properly and I can't figure out why.

[image: How it should look]

[image: How it looks for me]

```css
.app-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
/*this grabs all the children, which will be the flex items*/
.app-wrap>* {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
/*Header*/
.app-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
/*Content*/
.content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
/*Icon Bar*/
.icon-bar {
  display: flex;
}
.icon-bar a {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-wrap">
  <header class="app-header">
    <a href="#" class="button">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back
    </a>
    <h1>FlexBox App Layout</h1>
    <a href="#" class="button">
      <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
    </a>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, beatae?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque deserunt quisquam repellendus quia autem saepe culpa fugit nulla distinctio hic, beatae cum, perspiciatis iusto natus nesciunt itaque quaerat, earum ex.</p>
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/623184294521929728/LUJ4qL8n.jpg"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quo ipsa excepturi sunt, quibusdam, quos!
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi natus dolores placeat esse ratione fugiat voluptatum impedit blanditiis consequuntur quos debitis consequatur ea beatae fuga perspiciatis vero, mollitia, molestias omnis. Dolorum quas
      iusto, molestiae ut at architecto dolorem nulla est!</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. nulla, illum ea consectetur!</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. cumque ea, mollitia sequi quo consequatur dolor itaque numquam, aut tempore suscipit, ut quaerat. qui!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-bar">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Notifications
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Me
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: think we are missing some CSS - .icon-bar tray isn't being stylized

Comment: As you can see your code isn't enough to replicate the issue ... check the snippet

Comment: Here is a codepen @DaniP 
https://codepen.io/jcotzin/pen/zZPgqx

Comment: https://codepen.io/jcotzin/pen/zZPgqx @MikeDiglio

Comment: @Jessica you can use "align-items: center;" on the ".icon-bar" class and it should snap them all together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author was probably using Firefox while you're using Chrome. This is an issue with cross-browser compatibility where the author overlooked Chrome. Anyway, to fix your issue, scratch this part:

```
.app-wrap > * {
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

Among the 3 children of `.app-wrap`, only the `.content` can afford having a shrink-ed size. The other 2 (`.app-header` and `.icon-bar`) can't be allowed to shrink since their content will be distorted:

```
/*Header*/
.app-header {
  ...
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

/*Content*/
.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

/*Icon Bar*/
.icon-bar {
  ...
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

It should appear the same way on any browser now: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBagmJ

Comment: Thanks it worked! How do you handle browser cross compatibility?

Comment: Well you just have to open it on all common browsers to ensure it looks the same, make tweaks when it doesn't :D

Comment: In the same tutorial, he showed us about Gulp autoprefixer, which is supposed to change the css to make it cross browser compatible. Have you used it before?

Comment: Well it's another kind of cross browser compatible actually. You see, before the specs of a CSS feature is finalized, people already have a general idea of what it is - say border-radius: people already know it's to make rounded corner before the specs actually state that. Modern vendors compete to bring the most cutting edge feature to their vendors, so they usually implement those feature *before* the specs is finalized, resulting in a browser-specific property (for example -webkit-border-radius). gulp prefixer handles those cases, allowing people to use the newest features before its time.

Comment: thank, yea i actually found a good repo for flexbox bugs which should help with other cross compat issues. thanks again for your help :)